# Find the 3 highest values in a list (negatives included)

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm having trouble figuring out this interview cake problem

Given an array_of_ints, find the highest_values you can get from three of the integers.

```
Input: [-100, 5, 50, -200, 10, 1, 60]
Output: [-100, -200, 60]
```

Basically, ignore the negative sign and find the 3 highest values and append to a new array while keeping the negative sign on those values.  Here is my current work:

```
def highest_values(array):
    sort = sorted(array)
    new_array=[]
    while len(new_array)<3:
        for i in range(0,len(sort)):
            for j in sort[i:]:
                if abs(sort[i])>abs(j):
                    new_array.append(sort[i])
                    break
    print(new_array)

highest_values([-100, 5, 50, -200, 10, 1, 60])
```

However, I'm not getting the intended output.

Can I get some tips on my current code or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Thanks in advance!
Edit:(I made a grave error in the interpretation of the problem.  Now I understand that I need to find the greatest product from 3 values from the list)

Originally, I wanted to find the three highest values from the list while negating the negative sign.

Don't worry about answering this anymore; Technically, it was answered just below.  I'll re-approach the problem correctly tomorrow. Thanks for the help and tips.

You helped so much enrico.  Great advice and thank you for the help

Comment: If three of the selected values are negative, the result is also negative. So they won't give the highest product.

Comment: Your "basically" summary suggests that you've misunderstood the problem description. It's not just a question of finding the three greatest absolute values. For instance, if you had `[-5, -4, -3, 2]`, the result is `[-5, -4, 2]` (= `40`), not `[-5, -4, -3]` (= `-60`).

Comment: I made a grave error in the interpretation of the problem.  Sorry about the confusion.   With this new revelation thanks to tobias_k, I'm even more confused on how to approach this problem.  Any tips?

Comment: I suggest you clean this question and post another one where it is more clear that you are seeking advises on the algorithmic part. This way future readers can find this useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question deals with *product* but I don't see any product in your sample output.
If you just want to get the three highest values ignoring the sign you can just do:

```
sorted(array, key=abs, reverse=True)[:3]
```

Basically the `key` parameters allows you to specify a function that has to be applied on the elements of the list before doing the comparison. Here we are using `abs`to ignore the sign. The `reverse=True` is to impose a descendant order, then you can just get the first three elements.

You could also use the [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) function:

```
from heapq import nlargest
nlargest(3, array, key=abs)
```

Comment: What if those first three numbers are all negative, or only one is negative?

Comment: @tobias_k: So? The OP just said: "Basically, ignore the negative sign and find the 3 highest values and append to a new array while keeping the negative sign on those values."

Comment: That's OP's interpretation, but the actual question is "find the highest_product you can get from three of the integers", and with an odd number of nagatives, it will not be the highest product.

Comment: Ah, I made an error in my interpretation.  Thank's for catching that.  Although, that raises more questions on my part haha

Comment: @tobias_k: Wait, what do you mean for "That's the OP interpretation"? I thought that SO was about answering the questions from the OP, not trying to correct the OP on the understanding of his own question. The question he is talking about is not even linked.

Comment: Ah yes, `[:3]`, Python's "robot kitty" operator.

Comment: @AK: A suggestion for your next questions: Do not mix the problem and your interpretation of it unless you are sure they are equivalent. Otherwise just stick to the problem and then add your interpretation at the end, underlying that it is just your interpretation.